# how to keep spaces in wordpress content when published

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

There is an indentation blank in the edited code ,
but when i click publish in wordpress ,
the code format become the  following format.
How can i make the edited format not to be changed when publish it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try switch to Text mode, and use pre tag.

[image]